# OAuth Signature with XML request body

Tags: xml, oauth, signature

I need to know what the un-hashed, un-url-encoded OAuth signature looks like for a QuickBooks Online [Delete Customer](https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0050_Data_Services/0400_QuickBooks_Online/Customer#Deleting_a_Customer) API request.

Things to note

- There is a query in the url `?methodx=delete`.
- Where do I put the xml request body if necessary.

I was show to do it this way, but it doesn't seem to work, or follow the `x=y` paradigm.

```
POST
&
https://qbo.intuit.com/qbo36/resource/customer/v2/502724020/7
&
methodx=delete
&
oauth_consumer_key=9382hrq2li3rh9a8dshf98fh2fhe
&
oauth_nonce=2WM7s
&
oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1
&
oauth_timestamp=1344528249
&
oauth_token=a3helrikhiu23lfqiweahcnlik324hr2o3ihrfewewf
&
oauth_version=1.0
&
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Customer xmlns:ns2="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/qbo"
xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2"><Id>7</Id><SyncToken>0</SyncToken></Customer>
```

Comment: did you get this to work? i am struck with the same error can you please help

Comment: No I never did and I had exchanged multiple emails with quickbooks and they seemed to have no clue how their own API worked.

Comment: If you do figure it out please post an answer here!

Comment: sure i will post it if i get it working

Comment: not sure whether this may help you but it works ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762746/add-xml-request-body-to-oauth-iconsumerrequest/13775891#13775891

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should set the requests Content-Type header to "text/xml" and you should not append the XML to your request parameters when generating the oAuth signature.

POST parameters should only be included in the signature if they are of content-type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" as with a form submission.

I encountered the same problem, and found this solution on Linkedin's API documentation page:  <s>https://developer-programs.linkedin.com/documents/common-issues-oauth-authentication</s>  (dead link)