# add XML request body to Oauth IConsumerRequest

Tags: c#, rest, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

hi all am working on a project that involves Fetching data from Intuit Anywhere.The process works fine when a url signed with Oauth is send as request.Can some one help me how to add xml request to the body of  IConsumerRequest.

```
  OAuthConsumerContext consumerContext = new OAuthConsumerContext
                {
                    ConsumerKey = "consumerkey",
                    SignatureMethod = SignatureMethod.HmacSha1,
                    ConsumerSecret = "consumersecret"
                };

  OAuthSession oSession = new OAuthSession(consumerContext, "https://oauth.intuit.com/oauth/v1/get_request_token",
                                        "https://workplace.intuit.com/Connect/Begin",
                                        "https://oauth.intuit.com/oauth/v1/get_access_token");

                oSession.ConsumerContext.UseHeaderForOAuthParameters = true;
                oSession.AccessToken = new TokenBase
                {
                    Token = Session["accessToken"].ToString(),
                    ConsumerKey = "consumerkey",
                    TokenSecret = Session["accessTokenSecret"].ToString()
                };

                IConsumerRequest conReq = oSession.Request();
                 string body = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
    <AccountQuery xmlns=""http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2"">
      <ListIdSet>
        <Id idDomain=""QB"">143</Id>
        <Id idDomain=""QB"">130</Id>
      </ListIdSet>
    </AccountQuery>";
                    conReq = conReq.Get();
                conReq = conReq.ForUrl("https://services.intuit.com/sb/account/v2/536779769");
  conReq.RequestBody=body;
                   try
                {
                    conReq = conReq.SignWithToken();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
                string header = conReq.Context.GenerateOAuthParametersForHeader();
                string serviceResponse = conReq.ReadBody();
```

i get an error Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type.Can someone point me what the error is or Is it possible to do the same with a web request? Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this worked.Below is the example code i got from intuit forums-
https://idnforums.intuit.com/messageview.aspx?catid=86&threadid=18870&enterthread=y

```
 //using DevDefined.OAuth.Consumer;
//using DevDefined.OAuth.Framework;

protected void GetBalanceSheet()
{
    OAuthConsumerContext consumerContext = new OAuthConsumerContext
    {
        ConsumerKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["consumerKey"].ToString(),
        SignatureMethod = SignatureMethod.HmacSha1,
        ConsumerSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["consumerSecret"].ToString()
    };

    OAuthSession oSession = new OAuthSession(consumerContext, "https://oauth.intuit.com/oauth/v1/get_request_token",
                            "https://workplace.intuit.com/Connect/Begin",
                            "https://oauth.intuit.com/oauth/v1/get_access_token");

    oSession.ConsumerContext.UseHeaderForOAuthParameters = true;

    oSession.AccessToken = new TokenBase
    {
        Token = Session["accessToken"].ToString(),
        ConsumerKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["consumerKey"].ToString(),
        TokenSecret = Session["accessTokenSecret"].ToString()
    };

    var body = "<AdvancedReportQuery xmlns=\"http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xsi:schemaLocation=\"http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2 ..//RestDataFilter.xsd\"><BalanceSheetStd><OfferingId>ipp</OfferingId><EndTransactionDate>2012-06-01</EndTransactionDate></BalanceSheetStd></AdvancedReportQuery>";

    IConsumerRequest conReq = oSession.Request();
    conReq = conReq.Post().WithRawContentType("text/xml").WithRawContent(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(body)); ;
    conReq = conReq.ForUrl("https://services.intuit.com/sb/advancedreport/v2/508053445");
    try
    {
        conReq = conReq.SignWithToken();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }

    string serviceResponse = conReq.ReadBody();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Karthi,
It sounds like you are trying to do a GET request and add content to the body which would cause that error.

Please refer to the documentation on constructing the header for your request here:
https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0050_Data_Services/0500_QuickBooks_Windows/0100_Calling_Data_Services/0010_Request_Header

regards,
jarred

Comment: I even tried using post request.But did not get it to work.Finally got it working .Thanks for your answer

Comment: seems you are from ipp.i have a question are xml calls like the one above best suited for a website  or will using .net Devkit be fine

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question, but you can use the .Net SDK to call the IPP Rest APIs for your application from a website.

Comment: i mean to ask is there any advantage of using .Net SDK instead of rest APIs.

Comment: yes, the SDK provides additional functionality that you would other wise have to write your self. logging, events, retries etc. Additionally you can write one set of code to target the common entities in both QBO and QB Desktop.

Comment: can you point me out some sdk tutorials or samples.Thanks a lot for your help.